# Enforce LF line endings with CsvHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, line-endings, csvhelper

If I have some `LF` converted (using N++) CSV files, everytime I write data to them using JoshClose's `CsvHelper` the line endings are back to CRLF.

Since I'm having problems with CLRF `ROWTERMINATORS` in SQL Server, I whish to keep my line endings like the initital status of the file.

Couldn't find it in the culture settings, I compile my own version of the library.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Missing or incorrect `Newline` characters when using CsvHelper is a common problem with a simple but poorly documented solution. The other answers to this SO question are correct but are missing one important detail.

Configuration allows you to choose from one of four available alternatives:

```
// Pick one of these alternatives
CsvWriter.Configuration.NewLine = NewLine.CR;   
CsvWriter.Configuration.NewLine = NewLine.LF;
CsvWriter.Configuration.NewLine = NewLine.CRLF;
CsvWriter.Configuration.NewLine = NewLine.Environment;
```

However, many people are tripped up by the fact that (by design) `CsvWriter` does not emit any newline character when you write the header using `CsvWriter.WriteHeader()` nor when you write a single record using `CsvWriter.WriteRecord()`. The reason is so that you can write additional header elements or additional record elements, as you might do when your header and row data comes from two or more classes rather than from a single class.

CsvWriter **does** emit the defined type of newline when you call `CsvWriter.NextRecord()`, and the author, JoshClose, states that you are supposed to call `NextRecord()` after you are done with the header and after you are done with each individual row added using `WriteRecord`.  [See GitHub Issues List 929](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/929)

When you are writing multiple records using `WriteRecords()` CsvWriter automatically emits the defined type of newline at the end of each record.

In my opinion this ought to be much better documented, but there it is.

Comment: It's 2020 and the CsvHelper's documents still lacks important information and various samples. I faced the same problem that header and content were on a single line if using CsvWriter.WriteRecord(). CsvWriter.NextRecord() solved it! Thanks to you no more brain cells will be dying of it anymore :)

Comment: Adding even more confusion, CsvWriter.Flush() states `Serializes the row to the TextWriter.`, which would seemingly indicate the _row_ is finalized. It would be helpful if this method info hinted that you should call `NextRecord()` to write the NewLine char.

Comment: Doesn't read csv written by python csv library as of Aug 23, 2022.

Answer (score 9):

From what I can tell, the line terminator isn't controlled by CvsHelper.  I've gotten it to work by adjusting the File writer I pass to CsvWriter.

```
TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(filepathname);
tw.NewLine = "\n";
CsvWriter csvw = new CsvWriter(tw);
csvw.WriteRecords(records);
csvw.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 4):

Might be useful for somebody:

```
    public static void AppendToCsv(ShopDataModel shopRecord)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(DestinationFile, true))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csv.WriteRecord(shopRecord);
                writer.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

As of CsvHelper **13.0.0**, [line-endings are now configurable](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1408#issuecomment-575312060) via the `NewLine` configuration property.

E.g.:

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;

void Main()
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"my-file.csv"))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            csv.Configuration.NewLine = NewLine.LF; // <<####################

            var records = new List<Foo>
            {
                new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
                new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "two" },
            };

            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }
    }
}

private class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works between records, but can you get a newline between header and first record?

Comment: @RickyTad I'm not sure I understand your question. The sample code above does insert a new line after writing the header: `header\nrecord1\nrecord2` etc