# Wrong output when Write a list of class using CsvHelper in C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I would like to export my class  in .csv file, i follow this comment : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38088636/10152334

but when i export  (in Buses_Data.Buses_List), i have wrong data output, all data are on same line :

[image]

```
public void ExportToCSV(Buses_Data classToExport, string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Le fichier existe");
                System.IO.File.Delete(filepath);
                Console.WriteLine("l'ancien fichier à été supprimé");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Export :...");


            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath))
            using (CsvWriter cw = new CsvWriter(sw))
            {
                cw.WriteHeader<Bus>();

                foreach (Bus emp in classToExport.Buses_List)
                {
                    cw.WriteRecord<Bus>(emp);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Export CSV: OK");
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error ! " + i);
        }
    }
```

I don't know why the code doesn't work

Edit : 
Wrong output:
[image: Wrong output]

Right output (Data not corresponding)
[image: Right output (Data not corresponding)]

Edit 2 : 
I tried this comment : [Enforce LF line endings with CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420135/enforce-lf-line-endings-with-csvhelper)

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath))

            using (CsvWriter cw = new CsvWriter(sw))
            {
                cw.WriteHeader<Bus>();

                foreach (Bus emp in classToExport.Buses_List)
                {

                    cw.WriteRecord<Bus>(emp);
                    sw.NewLine = "\n";
                    cw.NextRecord();
                }
            }
```

I have better result but i Bus N°1 is on first line, not in second line

[image]

Solution :

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath))
            using (CsvWriter cw = new CsvWriter(sw))
            {
                cw.WriteHeader<Bus>();
                cw.NextRecord();
                foreach (Bus emp in classToExport.Buses_List)
                {

                    cw.WriteRecord<Bus>(emp);
                    //sw.NewLine = "\n";
                    cw.NextRecord();
                }
            }
```

Comment: CSV files is just text files with delimiters. Did you check the actual file? What does it contain? The screenshot posted here doesn't help at all

Comment: It could be that whatever program you used to **import** the CSV data didn't recognize the newline and ended up showing everything in the same line. When you double-click on a CSV file and expect it to open in Excel for example, Excel *imports* the data using the system's defaults for newlines, decimal and list separators. You'd have to go to `Data > From Text` to specify the delimiters you want

Comment: If you want to create files for Excel, why not create *actual* Excel files with a library like Epplus?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use Microsoft Office enterprise 2019, but it's work with other file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I add Two images, i open with Notepad++ if you want to compare, i don't use Epplus

Comment: Remove your `WriteHeader` method, `WriteRecords` also writes your header. Give a try?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have better results but i have same issue with first bus (in second edit)

Comment: @koviroli I have crash, isn't working :/

Comment: @Bensuperpc add a `NextRecord()` after `WriteHeader` too. That's what [CsvWriter](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs#L427) itself does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on answer of GitHub [issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/929), written by Josh Close:

> You need to call `NextRecord()` when you're done writing the header.
>   This is so you can write more fields manually before or after.

I tried it, it works well.

Comment: Good pointing this out also.  His output seems to indicate he'd need this  both places.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `CsvWriter.NextRecord`?

```
foreach (Bus emp in classToExport.Buses_List)
{
    cw.WriteRecord<Bus>(emp);
    cw.NextRecord();
}
```

Comment: That's not needed according to the [doc example](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#writing-a-csv-file)

Comment: Yes if OP changes their pattern to write all records.  I'm not sure if there is some other code they want to fire between each record write (logging, notification, etc.) so I didn't want to presume a refactor would be the answer.  The method is not depreciated, so I assume it's clearly part of the intended API use: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs

Comment: You're right. I keep forgetting how .... idiosyncratic the examples are, and that most of the time one has to check the tests, not the docs.

Comment: I tried (with other solution), I have better results (see my second edit)